# How to make a react component that records music?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make a react page that listens to music, just like shazam does. Do I have to use some API or something like that and how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

[ACR-Cloud](https://www.acrcloud.com/) allows you to scan audio files and it will recognize the song playing, unlike popular methods where the song is listened to in real-time and recognized, you can record the audio and scan it. However, it'll create the impression that you are listening to it in real-time. I think that's what you need.

On frontend, you can record a n(10 for ex) sec audio clip and send it to our backend which will perform the automatic recognition and send back the response to the front-end.

[Take a look at ThisSong-Backend(Python)](https://github.com/champ3oy/ThisSong-Backend)

[Shazam Clone UI Demo (Front End Demo with Reach Native)](https://github.com/kyle-belle/react-native-shazam)

[Also, there's an official ShazamKit](https://www.shazam.com/shazamkit)